# How to retrieve a result set from a raw query as a normal object instead of an stdClass in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I would know how to retrieve a result set from a raw query as a normal object instead of an stdClass in Laravel 4.

The same object using:

```
User::find(1);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do that with buil-in methods, but you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660964/port-stdclass-data-to-model/25663763#25663763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use raw queries with eloquent at any time and you'll get a Collection of models:

```
dd( User::select(DB::raw('created_at'))->get() );
```

Or a single model:

```
dd( User::select(DB::raw('created_at'))->first() );
```

Comment: Hey, It was good for a moment, but I have the same probleme and I can't use WHERE clause with your solution.

My query is quite complex with so much WHERE CLAUSE that I need to build in a string to concatenate..

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: If you cannot write a fluent query because your query is too complex, so you'll have to go full raw: `DB::select(DB::raw('your full query goes here'))->get()`;

Comment: In Fact it return A StdClass so the get method doesn't work.
I've just the found the solution using Model::whereRaw("foo = bar and 1 = 1 or (2 = 2 and 3 = 3)")->get().

source = http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/